# Get Logged user, while updating Model User with UpdateView in Django

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-authentication, django-users

new to Django here building my first project.
I´m using Django authentication and when user is logged, I show in a template panel the logged user using

```
<li>
                                    
  <a style="color: wheat;" href="#"><i class="fi-torso"></i>{{user.full_name}}</a>
  <ul class="menu vertical" style="background-color:rgb(51,51,51); border-color: wheat;">
    <li><a href="{% url 'users_app:user-logout' %}">Cerrar Sesión</a></li>
  </ul>

</li>
```

The thing is that logged user can modify other users attributes through UpdateView. So when I select user for updating (context user now is the user that is going to be updated), and I access Modify user template, in my panel instead of seeing logged user, I see the user that is being modify.

How can I diferenciate this? I understand why this is happening, but haven´t found how to solve it

Comment: Use `request.user` instead of just `user` (Also more indicative that this is the current user) to refer to the current logged in user. By default the context processors add the request and the user both to the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `user` is added to the context by one of the [Built-in template context processors](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/templates/api/#built-in-template-context-processors) namely `django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth`. There is also a context processor `django.template.context_processors.request` which adds the variable `request` to the context.

The problem is your `UpdateView` also adds the variable `user` to the context so that is the variable which is used. How to resolve this? The simplest method is to always use `request.user` to refer to the current user in the template.

Another solution is to simply change the name of the variable `UpdateView` will add to the context by setting `context_object_name`:

```
class MyView(UpdateView):
    ...
    context_object_name = 'other_user' # any preferred name
    ...
```

Now in the template one would refer to the user you are updating as `other_user`.

There is also the option of adding a custom context processor to the template which will add a variable with the requests user with a different name (perhaps `current_user`), but that would be doing too much work for this simple problem of clashing names.

Comment: Excelent answer! Thank you very much is working :)